# Can't qmake QtWebengine - "qtwebenginecore-config.pri: No such file or directory"

Tags: qt, makefile, config, qmake, qtwebengine

I built qt whit this configuration:

```
configure -v -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/doxa/raspi/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -opensource -confirm-license -sysroot /home/doxa/raspi/sysroot -make libs -nomake tests -nomake tools -nomake examples -skip qt3d -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtsensors -skip qtwayland -skip qtdeclarative -prefix /usr/local/doxas_5.12.4 -extprefix /usr/local/doxas_5.12.4 -hostprefix /usr/local/doxas_5.12.4 -qpa xcb -no-use-gold-linker
```

Everything done well but, QtWebengine didn't configure.
Now I want to build and install this module(I did with Qt 5.7), but qmake returns an error:

```
doxa@K43SD:/media/doxa/MCBK/rpi_build/websss$ /media/doxa/MCBK/rpi_build/qtbase/bin/qmake /usr/local/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/Src/qtwebengine/
Info: creating cache file /media/doxa/MCBK/rpi_build/websss/.qmake.cache
Cannot read /media/doxa/MCBK/rpi_build/websss/src/core/qtwebenginecore-config.pri: No such file or directory
Project ERROR: Could not find feature webengine-v8-snapshot-support.
doxa@K43SD:/media/doxa/MCBK/rpi_build/websss$
```

the *-config.pri is not available in the source of any module and it has to build during the module build process. I don't know how to generate this file. which tools of Qt should I use?

Qt: 5.12.4
Host: Ubuntu 18.04_x64

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Just found where is the problem.**

I should use the out of source **qmake**, where it is installed.

[Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/111202/can-t-qmake-qtwebengine-qtwebenginecore-config-pri-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
mkdir build_qtwebengine
cd buid_qtwebengine
/path/to/your/cross_compiled_Qt/bin/qmake /path/to/qtwebengine
```